# Как правильно сделать запрос через cURL и загрузить файл на сервер

Tags: php, curl

Ситуация следующая: у меня на хостинге в корне сайта расположен файл partners.rar и скрипт, через который будет производится загрузка файла на другой сервер.
Как загрузить файл из формы я знаю, т.е. выбрать файл на компьютере и загрузить на сервер, этот код работает, 
ФОРМА:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea placeholder="Текст новости" class="form-control" name="text" rows="9"></textarea>
<input name="attachment" class="btn btn-default" onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value" type="file">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg m-b-5 pull-right">Добавить новость</button>
</form>
```

ОБРАБОТЧИК:

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
$storeFolder = 'assets/images/tickets';   //2
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];          //3             
$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
$targetFile =  "assets/images/tickets/".$_FILES['attachment']['name'];  //5
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
}
```

а вот как мне загрузить файл на другой сервер, и загрузить этот файл не с компьютера через форму, а с хостинга через скрипт?

Если я загружаю через форму то в fiddlere показывает такой запрос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я делаю такой запрос:

```
// загрузка файла
function uploadfile($url){

    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt","w");
    fclose($fp);
    $uploadfile = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($uploadfile, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($uploadfile, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($uploadfile, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 9);
    curl_setopt($uploadfile, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($uploadfile, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    if(stristr($url, 'https') === TRUE) {
    curl_setopt ($uploadfile, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($uploadfile, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  }
    curl_setopt($uploadfile, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($uploadfile, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($uploadfile, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($uploadfile, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($uploadfile, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="a"=FilesMAn&Content-Disposition: form-data; name="c"=/home/booniff/public_html/AAAAAAAAAAA/&Content-Disposition: form-data; name="p1"=uploadFile&Content-Disposition: form-data; name="charset"=UTF-8&Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f"; filename="partners.rar" Content-Type: application/octet-stream=<file>');

    $result = curl_exec ($uploadfile);
    if (curl_errno($uploadfile)) {
        return curl_error($uploadfile);
    } else {
        return $result;
    }

    curl_close ($uploadfile);
        unset($uploadfile);
    }// конец функции
```

Помогите пожалуйста сформировать код загрузки файла через cUrl, чтобы загрузился файл на сервер, взятый с хостинга, на котором расположен скрипт загрузки.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю нужно ли вам действительно столько параметров для `curl`, если действительно нужно то добавьте, а так попробуйте использовать такой код:

```
// загрузка файла
function uploadfile($url){

    $file = '/path/to/file.zip';
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { // php 5.5+
        $cFile = curl_file_create($file);
    } else { // 
        $cFile = '@' . realpath($file);
    }
    $post = array('file_contents'=> $cFile);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}// конец функции
```